# TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function () {
    this.myVar = 'example';
    console.log(this.myVar);
};
```

I get the error:

```
/home/karl/mymodule.js:3
    this.myVar = 'example';
               ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'myVar' of undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In strict mode `this` is `undefined`. But in non-strict mode `this` is nothing but pointing to `GLOBAL`. So here you are trying to set something to `undefined`.

Where exactly were you intending to attach `myVar`? On your `module`? Or on `GLOBAL`? If it's on `GLOBAL` (which is actually a bad idea), use `GLOBAL.myVar` or `global.myVar`. If it's on your module you could do `module.exports.myVar = 'example';`